# Synergy 1.4.10 only sharing mouse not keyboard

Tags: synergy

Just installed Synergy for the first time. Server is Mac OS X 10.8.2 and the client is Windows 2008 R2 x64. Initially it all worked perfectly and beautiful. But then about about 10 minutes the keyboard stopped working on the Windows machine. I could still use the mouse but whatever I typed went to the Mac. Rebooting the Windows machine resulted in my actually being able to type my password to login but after that the keyboard just got stuck on the Mac. Restarting the client, and even running older versions of the Mac software, did not help.

Comment: Having the same issue. Mac OS X 10.8.2 Server, Windows 7 CLient